# JSONP: status code 200 OK e mesmo assim retorna $.Ajax(...error:function()...)

Tags: ajax, return, jsonp

Estamos tendo dificuldades em realizarmos uma requisção `$.ajax`, JSONP.
O problema é que mesmo com o retorno positivo (Status Code:200) a função mostrada abaixo sempre retorna o resultado de verificação de erro como positivo.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#checar', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:     'GET',
                url:      'http://sinpesq.mpa.gov.br/rgp/web/sargp/index.php/atividade_pesca_profissional/atividade/RegularidadePescador',
                data:     {cpf: '37430564291', dtnascimento: '26-02-1970'},
                dataType: 'jsonp',

                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(error.message);
                },

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });         
    });
```

[image: requisições]
[image: retorno da requisição e o retorno jquery que diz: jQuery210027153274044394493_1423956716453 was not called]

E nada é retornado. Como recuperar os dados JSON dessa requisição?

Comment: Isto ocorre por que você está usando um domínio externo sem CORS (eu acho).

Comment: Isso só vai funcionar se o servidor responder com `Content-type: application/javascript`.

Comment: A resposta parece JSON comum, já tentou com `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: O seu exemplo no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3tbgbvm/
Da a seguinte mensagem de erro: Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.

Comment: bfavaretto, obrigado pela sua atenção. Usar o datatype como 'json' não funcionaria porque é uma requisição cross-domain, q requer jsonp.

Comment: QMechanic73, desde já agradeço pela sua atenção, mesmo modificando o script conforme sua sugestão o retorno apontado pelo console foi: "myCallback was not called".
Eu já havia tentado essa abordagem ( e mesmo assim o 'bigown' me negativou alegando: "falta de pesquisa"...)

Comment: Como você sabe quem te negativou e o motivo? Eu que sou moderador não sei. Não vejo nada que indique quem foi, nem o porquê.

Comment: @Milhomens eu não negativei sua pergunta. Muito menos você, até porque o *site* não permite negativar pessoas. Eu editei para melhorar o estilo da pergunta. Eu estava lhe ajudando sem mudar a essência da pergunta. Pior, sei lá porque você resolveu dizer que eu aleguei algo. De onde você tirou isto?

Comment: Srs., desculpem o transtorno do mau entendido. Não passou de uma interpretação errônea aqui da minha parte. Sinceros pedidos de desculpas e agradecimento ao esforço de cada um em ajudar à sua maneira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP é diferente de JSON. JSON é um formato de serialização de dados, quando você faz uma requisição esperando um JSON o servidor deve retornar um conteúdo de texto. E de fato, é isso que o seu servidor está retornando.

```
[{bla},{bla},{bla}]
```

O JSONP (JSON com *padding*), por outro lado, espera que a resposta seja um script em JavaScript. Por que? Justamente porque a tag `<script>` é uma das exceções à Política de Mesma Origem (e portanto um domínio pode incluir na página scripts de outro domínio). Para isso funcionar, entretanto, é necessário um "truque":

1. O browser cria um elemento `script`, colocando a URL a ser consultada **e um parâmetro adicional especificando o nome de uma função**. Exemplo:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dominio/url?callback=myCallback">
   ```

   (`myCallback` é só um exemplo - qualquer outro nome de função poderia ser usado)
2. O servidor prepara a resposta JSON, normal, só que na hora de enviar, o faz com o *content-type* `text/javascript` (ou `application/javascript`, mas se  bem me lembro este dá problema em alguns browsers mais antigos) e o mais importante: **colocando um *padding***:

   ```
   myCallback([{bla}, {bla}, {bla}]);
   ```

   Sem esse `myCallback(` no início e `);` no final a chamada JSONP não funciona - afinal, tudo o que vai vir é um objeto JavaScript normal:

   ```
   [{bla}, {bla}, {bla}]
   ```

   que não vai executar código algum, nem vai ser salvo em variável nenhuma, e nada vai acontecer...

Pelo visto você modificou o servidor para servir o *content-type* correto, mas se esqueceu de adicionar o *padding*. Por isso o jQuery - ao constatar que o script foi carregado e executou corretamente, mas a função de *callback* não foi chamada - acusa o erro.

A solução é modificar o servidor para fazer o *padding* (lembrando: é pra usar o nome estabelecido no parâmetro da *query string*, não necessariamente `myCallback`). Agora, se o servidor não é seu, mas de terceiros (de modo que você não possa modificá-lo), receio que sua única saída seja usar um *proxy* (por exemplo, fazendo com que seu próprio servidor acesse o servidor de terceiros e devolva o resultado pro cliente). Nesse caso, não será necessário mexer com JSONP (nem CORS) - pode-se apenas usar JSON e pronto...

Comment: mgibsonbr, obrigado pela sua atenção. Esclarecedor. Encontrei uma alternativa para a obtenção dos dados: XDomain, em github.com/jpillora/xdomain, no entanto, ele só me retorna dados do tipo text. Já tentei modificá-lo para que me retornasse no formato json mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Não é só fazer um `JSON.parse(texto)` nos dados recebidos?