# Como garantir que o JSON gerado não retorne erro para o Cliente?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, cors

Criei uma Web API que retorna um `JSON` e que está com um problema parecido com a questão [JSONP: status code 200 OK e mesmo assim retorna $.Ajax(…error:function()…)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50800/jsonp-status-code-200-ok-e-mesmo-assim-retorna-ajax-errorfunction).
O cliente consome a API com o Nodes assim:

```
refresh() {
        axios
            .get(`${URL}"${this.generateDate()}"`)

            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
                this.setState({ ...this.state, services: resp.data, loading: false });

                let statusModal = swal.getState();

                //if (!statusModal.isOpen) {
                //  swal.close();
                //}
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log('O erro é =>', e);
                //swal('Ocorreu algum problema!', 'Entre em contato com o responsável', 'error');
                //this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: false });
            });
    }
```

O retorno do JSON é 200, porém no console exibe o erro descrito mais abaixo 
Decorei o método API com o [Cors](https://enable-cors.org/index.html) para obter a conpatibilidade de origens, no entanto o erro persiste.

**Minha dúvida é:**

Somente este trecho de código onde eu decoro o método api é suficiente ?

**Esta é o método da API:** melhorado conforme sugestão do [Danilo Ribeiro da Silva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/113700/danilo-ribeiro-da-silveira)

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/monitora")]
    public class MonitoraController : ApiController
    {

        // GET: api/Painel/5
        [Route("GetPainel")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPainel(string dtHoraExecuta)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtHoraExecuta.Replace("\"", ""), out dt))
                    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable); // 406


                List<ProductType> lreturn = new List<ProductType>();
                PainelMonitoracaoBusiness obj = new PainelMonitoracaoBusiness();
                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dtHoraExecuta.Replace("\"", "")));

                var _painel = obj.ObterDadosPainel(dt);

                if (_painel == null)
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Não foram encontrado dados para esse período. = {0}", dtHoraExecuta)),
                        ReasonPhrase = "Serviços não encontrados."
                    };
                    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < _painel.Count; i++)
                {

                    ProductType prd = new ProductType();

                    for (int z = 0; z < _painel[i].lservices.Count; z++)
                    {
                        if (_painel[i].ID_SERVICO == _painel[i].lservices[z].ID_SERVICO)
                        {
                            prd.productType = _painel[i].productType;
                            SubServico subServico = new SubServico();
                            subServico.statusAll = _painel[i].lservices[z].statusAll;
                            subServico.subtype = _painel[i].lservices[z].subtype;

                            Info infoAbertura = new Info();
                            infoAbertura.mount = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[0].mount;
                            infoAbertura.status = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[0].status;
                            infoAbertura.type = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[0].type;

                            Info infoFechamento = new Info();
                            infoFechamento.mount = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[1].mount;
                            infoFechamento.status = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[1].status;
                            infoFechamento.type = _painel[z].lservices[0].info[1].type;

                            subServico.info.Add(infoAbertura);
                            subServico.info.Add(infoFechamento);

                            prd.services.Add(subServico);
                        }                        
                    }
                    lreturn.Add(prd);
                }

                return Ok(lreturn);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed); // 417
            }
        }
```

**Este é o erro que capturei no browser:**

```
 erro é => TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

**Imagem do erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja qual é a linha do erro

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tratar os erros de acordo com o status code do response assim como fez quando não encontrou o painel.

O que eu recomendo é sempre validar as entradas de dados dos usuários.
No caso do seu `Convert.ToDateTime` troque pelo `DateTime.TryParse` que você consegue fazer essa validação de forma simples.

Sempre coloco um bloco de try catch com um retorno que não mostre o erro para o usuário.

Veja que a mesma action tem vários retornos de status:

- 406 Not Acceptable - Quando a entrada de dados do usuário for
  inválida
- 404 Not Found - Quando não encontrar o painel
- 417 Expectation Failed - Quando acontecer algum erro interno
- 200 OK - Quando sucesso

Exemplo abaixo:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPainel(string dtHoraExecuta)
{
    try
    {
        // Verifica se os dados passados pelo cliente são válidos
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable); // 406

        // Verifica se os dados passados pelo cliente são válidos
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        if(!DateTime.TryParse(dtHoraExecuta.Replace("\"", ""), out dt))
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable); // 406

        // Obtem os dados...
        if (dados == null)
            return NotFound();

        //...

        return Ok(dados)
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Erro interno do servidor
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed); // 417
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Danilo Ribeiro da Silveira mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Quando você acessa a API via GET direto pela URL (fora da sua aplicação) ela funciona?
Até aonde estou entendendo na imagem que você publicou, o erro é gerado pelo sweetalert e não é um erro da API.
Você deve estar acessando uma propriedade do response que não existe e passando para o sweetalert não?

Comment: a aplicação funciona quando chamo fora da aplicação sim e consegui mais informações e vou editar meu post.

Comment: Sua condição para fechar o modal esta errada. Você só pode fechar o modal se ele estiver aberto. No seu caso você esta negando isso. O correto seria if (statusModal.isOpen) { swal.close(); }

Comment: não conheço `ract` peguei esse código de outro sistema que consome minha `API` e o programador falou que apesar de ser estranho é assim mesmo rs, por `Default` é `false` daí então existe a negação` !`.

Comment: Não tem dessa de `Default` é `false`. O método `swal.getState()` pega as informações do modal e tem a propriedade isOpen que vai te falar se existe o modal aberto ou fechado. Se estiver fechado ela retorna `false` e se estiver aberto retorna `true` é simples. Retire a negação e veja que não vai dar mais o erro. Você pode testar direto no site do https://sweetalert.js.org/ e digitar no console `if (swal.getState().isOpen) { swal.close(); }`

Comment: O tipo de erro `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` não tem haver com verificação da janela popup: Aberta ou Fechada tanto que pedi para que o desenvolvedor desabilitasse a verificação e persiste o erro acredito que seja algo relacionado a dominios diferentes como nesse artigo [enable cors](https://enable-cors.org/index.html)